# pick 8 cards from a deck of 52 cards with at least two queens

Tags: combinatorics

> pick 8 cards from a deck of 52 cards with at least two queens.

I did $C^4_2 \cdot C^{50}_6$ which was wrong. My reasoning was that if I pick 2 queens with $C^4_2$, then it doesn't matter which of the remaining 50 cards that are picked there will be at least two queens.

The correct answer uses the sum of the combinations with exactly 2 queens, exactly 3 queens and exactly 4 queens, i.e.

$$C^4_2 \cdot C^{48}_6 \;+\; C^4_3 \cdot C^{48}_5 \;+\; C^4_4 \cdot C^{48}_4.$$

I just don't understand why my first method is wrong, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first method overcounts those hands with more than $2$ Queens.  Specifically, given such a hand, there is no way to know which of the queens were the "special two" and which came in the general selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, you want to choose 8 cards with **at least** two queens. In your answer, you choose exactly 2 queens out of 4, and then pick 6 out of remaining 50 cards which **may still contain** queens.

But we have four different queens. Let's name them Q1 and Q2 and Q3 and Q4.

Suppose for example in one situation, you first get Q1 and Q2, and next you get Q3 and five other cards.
In another situation, you get Q1 and Q3 at first and next you get Q2 with other 5 cards.
So this situations are the same. So you are overcounting.

Comment: but if I do 4C2 I am picking 2 queens, and the remaining 50C6 combinations will also contain the possibilities of getting the third or fourth queen

Comment: I noticed the previous answer was wrong. Now I edited it. @Paul